# Get multiple values of dropdown values

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using PhP. I have 3 dropdown lists, one for continent, other for country and 3rd for cities. I want to get multiple continents, countries and cities. I have 3 buttons for these dropdown lists. I have attached click events with these buttons in jquery. If I want to select multiple continents then I select the continent from dropdown list and click the button. Then click event is called and I save the values in an array and process is repeated for next continent. In jquery, I have 3 arrays for continents, countries and cities. How can I store these arrays in database when form is submitted.
[image]

Comment: use ajax ?? or do u want to store array or array's data??

Comment: I want to store array's data along with other data in the database on form submission.

Comment: $('#addcountry').click(function() {
  var countries = [];
  var country = $('#language :selected').text();
  countries.push(country);
  
  
});

Comment: addcountry is name of the button that is used to add countries in the array. I have other arrays for cities, languages etc that I want to store in database with some php data.

Comment: like array('countries'=>array(1,2,3)) and array('cities'=>array(1,2,3))???

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="continent">
<option>
</option>
<option value="America">America
</option>
<option value="Asia">Asia
</option>
</select>
<select class="country">

</select>
<script>
$(".continent").change(function(){
    var cou=new Object();///country
    cou['America']=['USA','Example'];
    cou['Asia']=['IRAN','Example','Example2'];
    var sel=$(".continent").val();
    for(var j=0;j<cou[sel].length;j++)
        {
            $('.country').append("<option value="+cou[sel][j]+">"+cou[sel][j]+"</option>");
        }
    })
</script>
```